# Error in porting a proxy sever in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, proxy-server

I am trying port a proxy (Python Proxy) on Google App Engine; When I am running this code in Development mode, and trying to access any page via this proxy I am getting the following Error:

```
INFO     2013-10-09 14:50:56,539 sdk_update_checker.py:245] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-10-09 14:50:57,029 sdk_update_checker.py:289] This SDK release is newer than the advertised release.
INFO     2013-10-09 14:50:57,046 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: URL
INFO     2013-10-09 14:50:57,058 dispatcher.py:168] Starting module "default" running at:URL
INFO     2013-10-09 14:50:57,060 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at:URL
ERROR    2013-10-09 14:51:04,284 webapp2.py:1528] __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shekhar/appengine/python/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/shekhar/appengine/python/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/shekhar/appengine/python/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/shekhar/appengine/python/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1076, in __call__
    handler = self.handler(request, response)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
INFO     2013-10-09 14:51:04,289 module.py:599] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 228
```

Proxy is code is below

```
class ConnectionHandler:
    def __init__(self, connection, address, timeout):
        self.initialize(request, response);
        self.client = connection
        self.client_buffer = ''
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.method, self.path, self.protocol = self.get_base_header()
        if self.method=='CONNECT':
            self.method_CONNECT()
        elif self.method in ('OPTIONS', 'GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT',
                             'DELETE', 'TRACE'):
            self.method_others()
        self.client.close()
        self.target.close()
```

Comment: init takes 4 arguments and you are passing it 3. Start there? Got a debugger? See what you can actually calling it with.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have defined a custom class and are using it as a response handler. But response handlers have a specific contract: they must accept `request` and `response`, then call `initialize`. That is usually done by inheriting from `webapp2.RequestHandler`. See the webapp2 documentation on [overriding `__init__`](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#overriding-init).

I have no idea how you are expecting your `connection`, `address`, and `timeout` parameters to be passed. Maybe you meant to override `get()` instead of `__init__()`?